# Convert a TIME8. to a Character Without First Converting to Numeric Format

Tags: syntax, sas

I am trying to convert a `TIME8.` value to a character variable in the same original format the `TIME8.` was in. For example, if the value is `12:30:00`, I want a character value that also appears as `12:30:00`.

If I try to simply use a `PUT('12:30:00'T,8.)`  statement to convert it, it will first convert it to its raw form, which is 1800 (the number of seconds since 12:00).

How can I keep the format? With the colons and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the format **TIME8.** instead of **8.** as shown below,

```
data _null_;
  val='12:30:00'T;
  num=put(val,time8.);
  put _all_;
run;
```

Log,

```
1266  data test;
1267    val='12:30:00'T;
1268    num=put(val,time8.);
1269    put _all_;
1270  run;

val=45000 num=12:30:00 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `vvalue` function, which returns a character value formatted in the same way as the original value.  This way you don't need to find out beforehand what format the number is in.

This will only work if your original values are stored as variables, rather than hard coding the value as in your example.  If you just have hard coded values then you'll need to use the method in the answer from @Vishant.

```
data _null_;
  val='12:30:00'T;
  format val time8.;
  num=vvalue(val);
  put _all_;
run;
```